# Diff between 2 ways changing useradd defaults

Tags: user-management, useradd

I'm trying to change the useradd default shell,  so when the next new user created its shell would be /usr/sbin/tcsh.

One way doing that is by running the following command :

```
useradd -D -s /usr/sbin/tcsh
```

Another way is by editing the /etc/default/useradd:

```
SHELL=/usr/sbin/tcsh
```

I was wondering what is the difference between the two options?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no effective difference.  There are many ways of setting  configuration.  They both edit the `SHELL` variable in the `/etc/default/useradd` file.

Check the man page with:

```
$ man useradd
```

Then look for the `-s` argument.

One might be more convenient or easier to remember than the other for some users.  Since you have already tested both, you can decide for yourself which is easier for you to remember or use.

Answer (score 0):

In the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/useradd.8.html) for `useradd` the normal behaviour of the `-s` option is:

> -s, --shell SHELL
>              The name of the user's login shell. The default is to leave this
>              field blank, which causes the system to select the default login
>              shell specified by the SHELL variable in /etc/default/useradd, or
>              an empty string by default.

The `-s` option when invoked with  `-D` behaves as follows:

> -s, --shell SHELL
>
> The name of a new user's login shell.
>
> This option sets the SHELL variable in /etc/default/useradd.

So both methods set the SHELL variable in the `/etc/default/useradd` file.